# Google Visualization JSON PHP

Tags: json, google-visualization

I spent the whole day trying to get a pie chart with Google Charts.
I am getting my results from a MySQL Database using PHP.
The result is a JSON which looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[cols] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [label] => Firma
                [type] => string
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [label] => Zeit
                [type] => number
            )

    )

[rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Firma] => Firma1
                [Zeit] => 60
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Firma] => Firma2
                [Zeit] => 40
            )

    )

)
```

Javascript Code looks like this:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsongesamtzeiten;?>);
    //data.addColumn('string', 'Firma');
    //data.addColumn('number', 'Zeit');
    //data.addRows([ ['Firma1',40], ['Firma2',60] ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Arbeitsverteilung gesamt',
      colors: ['#3B2BC1', '#7EBB58'],        
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      backgroundColor: { stroke: "#CCC", strokeWidth: 2, fill: "#f5f5f5" }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
```

I get a:

```
 Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

as reply.

If I uncomment the `data.addColumn` and `data.addRows` and remove the `<?=$jsongesamtzeiten;?>` it works. But that's not what I want, because I want to recieve the data from a MySQL-database.
I did many google-searches and found some similiar questions here, but nothing helped me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in the JSON rows column value keys.
It appears you're naming the object keys according to their column labels.
However, the key for a value should simply be `v`
See the first example under the [DataTable class reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)

Try changing the JSON as follows...

```
stdClass Object
(
  [cols] => Array
    (
      [0] => stdClass Object
          (
              [label] => Firma
              [type] => string
          )

      [1] => stdClass Object
          (
              [label] => Zeit
              [type] => number
          )
    )

  [rows] => Array
    (
      [0] => stdClass Object
          (
              [v] => Firma1
              [v] => 60
          )

      [1] => stdClass Object
          (
              [v] => Firma2
              [v] => 40
          )
    )
)
```

Also, since you're already including the column and row definitions in your JSON,
you will not need to use `data.addColumn` or `data.addRows`

only need...
`var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsongesamtzeiten;?>);`
(once the format is correct)